# Understanding Parseval's Theorem with Discrete Wavelet Transform

Tags: discrete-signals, python, wavelet, transform, parseval

I have difficulty to understand the results I get with implementing Parseval's Theorem in Python to DWT. I have the good results getting the Energy with Fourier transform and the time series in python:

```
# Parseval theorem energy
def ParsevalTheorem(data):
    energy_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        energy_sum += abs(data[i])**2
    return energy_sum

# dwt_data[0] => approximation component at final level, dwt_data[1:] => detail components
def DWTParseval(dwt_data):
    details_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(dwt_data)-1):
        details_sum += ParsevalTheorem(dwt_data[i+1])
    approx_sum = ParsevalTheorem(dwt_data[0])
    final_sum = approx_sum + details_sum
    return final_sum

fourierTransform = np.fft.fft(short_signal)
print("fourier energy: ", ParsevalTheorem(np.abs(fourierTransform))/len(fourierTransform))
print("Org energy: ", ParsevalTheorem(short_signal))
print("DWT energy: ", DWTParseval(app1)) # app1 is haar discrete wavelet transform using pywt.wavedec(data, "haar", level = 3)
```

Results:

```
fourier energy:  1305035.7546624008
Org energy:  1305035.7546624022
DWT energy:  1309077.6827128115
```

I've gathered the information on using Parseval Theorem from equation: [Equation Link1](https://cnx.org/contents/EQurkhlI@6.9:8jovwc5A@4/Generalizations-of-the-Basic-Multiresolution-Wavelet-System)

[image: https://cnx.org/contents/EQurkhlI@6.9:8jovwc5A@4/Generalizations-of-the-Basic-Multiresolution-Wavelet-System]

I have also encountered another equation to get the Energy but if I divide the Approximation sum with it's length it's in whole different scope than the original signal energy: [Equation Link2](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9b27/89bbecd8ba9f82e011899c23f150426f0072.pdf?_ga=2.220456860.526776093.1594102586-792081026.1594102586)

[image]

I some what understand the Parseval theorem when dealing with fourier transform, but lost with these equations when dealing with DWT.

PS: I know there is more Pythonic way to do the code but I intend to apply it in a different language also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) and [Plancherel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) finally boil down to **orthogonality**. When one decomposes a data (with samples), via a scalar product, onto an  orthogonal sequence (yielding coefficients), **there exists a certain preservation (equality, up to a proportionality factor) of energy between samples and coefficients**. There are some technical conditions, and in certain cases, one only get inequalities (cf. [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality)) or frame bounds.

The equation for the discrete wavelet transform (DWT) might be incomplete, with respect to the indices. I for instance think that in the second term of the RHS, the scaling factor should be $N_j$, not $N_J$ (and this depends a bit on how discrete wavelets are implemented). Basically, an orthogonal wavelet transform projects data onto basis elements gathered in groups called subbands. Each wavelet subband comes from $N_j$ vectors, with an additional $N_J$ vectors for the approximation. And normally, the total number of vectors  should be (about, honestly, this depends on signal extension) the number of samples $N$, in other words: $N=N_J +\sum_{j=1}^JN_j$.

Comment: "technical coefficients"? :)

Comment: Excellent... Corrected